# data not showing completely inside panel

Tags: c#, windows

Hi I'm working on Windows application and I'm adding data inside the panel dynamically however data is not showing it completely inside the panel because of font size but I don't want to resize font.

```
tblLayoutModule.Controls.Add(new Label() { 
  Text = string.Concat(pModuleName, "  ", pVersion), 
  Padding = new Padding() { Top = 2 },
  UseMnemonic = false }
);
```

Comment: See [Form.ResizeEnd Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.resizeend?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add `autosize = true` could work for you

```
 tblLayoutModule.Controls.Add(
     new Label() { 
        Autosize = true, 
        Text = string.Concat(pModuleName,"",pVersion), 
        Padding = new Padding() { Top = 2 },
        UseMnemonic = false }
     );
```